# mediaplayer.prepare, How to Avoid Toast delay. "Loading"

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

how to avoid delay toast while mediaplayer.prepare, i want to show the toast when btn onclick.

```
FloatingActionButton button = findViewById(R.id.playbtnnine);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Stop" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }else {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Set an [`OnPreparedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)) on the MediaPlayer, and do the `setLooping()` and `start()` calls in that. Then use the [`prepareAsync()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync()) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this

```
 FloatingActionButton button = findViewById(R.id.playbtnnine);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Stop" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }else {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                 }
        }
    });
```